# How to add nodereference link to a view

Tags: nodes

I have two content types.

- Images
- Question

The **question content type** is meant to allow users to ask questions about the photos in the **images content type**.

I added a *node reference field* with "*reference from url*" type selected to the question content type. I checked "create link on the full view" during the setup. This works correctly if I go to an "images" node.

However, I am displaying the "image" type in a view. So far I can not figure out how to get a link to the question content type to show on the view. I have tried this using a "references" display type of the view, but still nothing.

Answer (score 1):

**Set up the relationship**:

- Under the **Relationships** section in advance settings. click + to add a relationship.
- Under "Add relationships" you will see all fields listed.
- Drop down the Groups menu and select "Content".
- Locate your node reference field, for example '**Content: Reference question** (field_reference_question)'. Check the box to the left of it.
- Click the Add button.
- Check the box labeled '**Require this relationship**', and click the Update button.

**Add a field**:

- Click + next to Fields. Under Groups, select Node, and choose Node: Title. Under Relationship, select your node reference field, e.g., Reference question, click Update.

Answer (score 0):

In your view you need to add your question type in the **References** in Advanced Settings.

Then as you add your field to the view you create, in the **Relationship** drop down, chose your *relationship name* (the default is **Do not use relationship**)